# Exposing Smart Contract over HTTP

Tags: solidity, web3js, json-rpc

Would like to deploy a smart contract that any Web2 user can communicate with -
 given my smart contract public functions accept a few parameters.

This essentially makes it "centralized" in a way, as my HTTP API gateway will be the funnel to the Ethereum network.

How can I solve such problem ? What is the best approach to this ?

Answer (score 2):

The closer you could get to that, as far as I know, would be to deploy your smart contracts through Infura.

Infura allows a web/mobile browser to read data from the blockchain without the need to be running a full node or using Metamask.

Notice that your users will not be able to send transactions (save data) just read it.

Comment: I'm mostly talking about sending parameters to a smart contract rather than reading from it.